# Write multiple arrays with different format (string and numbers) python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am very new to python and I would like to write the following (something like fprintf in matlab) I do not know why this string not working ???

Here is the code

```
import numpy as np 
coord=np.linspace(0,10,5)
keyy=("LE")
key=np.repeat(keyy,5)
out_arr=np.array_str(key)
zip=np.array([coord,out_arr])
zzip=zip.T
print(zzip)
savefile=np.savetxt("nam.dat",zzip,fmt="%f %s")
```

Comment: What are you getting?  What would you like to be getting?  We need more details.

Comment: I got the following error:
 VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray.

Comment: zip=np.array([coord,out_arr])
[array([ 0. ,  2.5,  5. ,  7.5, 10. ]) "['LE' 'LE' 'LE' 'LE' 'LE']"]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\MAC_folder\python\two.py", line 9, in <module>
    savefile=np.savetxt("nam.dat",zzip,fmt="%f %s")
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in savetxt
  File "C:\Users\moham\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 1415, in savetxt
    raise error
ValueError: fmt has wrong number of % formats:  %f %s

Comment: I would like to have a 5 rows, and 2 columns includes the following:
0    2.5  5   7.5 10 
LE   LE  LE  LE   LE

trying to write it down the way I want, by I can not ??
should like zip array

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the following line:

```
out_arr=np.array_str(key)
```

This is converting the array `['LE' 'LE' 'LE' 'LE' 'LE']` to the *string* `"['LE' 'LE' 'LE' 'LE' 'LE']"`. Note the quotes. This is no longer an array, it is a single string, and numpy interprets it as a length-1 array.  You first need to drop that line:

```
key=np.repeat(keyy,5)
zip=np.array([coord,key])
```

The next problem you will run into is that this will convert the `coord` numbers into strings, resulting in all elements being string. This is because numpy arrays have a single, fixed type (there are exceptions but they are more complicated). And the only way to do that in this case is to make everything a string.

The simple way around this is to use an "object" array (basically the same as a cell array in python), which stores arbitrary python objects rather than fixed data:

```
zip=np.array([coord,out_arr], dtype='object')
```

However, the better solution if you can is to use pandas. Pandas is sort of like MATLAB tables, but much more powerful. It is designed for this sort of data, and has very nice functions for writing text files like you want to do here in a cleaner, more explicit way.

Also, `zip` is a built-in function, and it is better not to name variables the same names as built-in functions. It is allowed, but `zip` is an important function and you don't want to block access to it.

Comment: Thanks for your clear explanation, 
I tried with Pandas, but seems not very useful for what i want, I just amazed how Python does not have a way to write data includes different types ??
like fprintf in matlab, and then specify format for each row or column ??
 But thanks again..!

Comment: @Sci_tech: You can absolutely do that in Python, in several ways. You can keep the the columns as a list, e.g. `cols = [coord,out_arr]`, for example. It is just that people rarely do that anymore because pandas is so much simpler and more powerful.